# Wordpress blog category does not show parent in slug

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having the following issue and I have no clue as to how to resolve it:
1: I have the following post category structure (all the post categories, native post categories that is, are children of the "blog" category)

- /blog/category-1
- /blog/category-2
- ...
  2: My problem is that **mydomain.com/category-1** shows the posts from that category when it should go to **mydomain.com/blog/category**

I do not want to use redirect as some categories may interfere with future pages

I really have no idea where to start

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with Permalink Manager LIte plugin

Comment: I know you're answering your own question, but stackoverflow questions and answers are public so other people with the same problem can find and learn from them. It would be nice if you could describe a bit more how exactly that plugin solves the problem, so others could reproduce your solution.